# What Type of date time is this?

Tags: datetime, date

I received these details from a function in Paypal. It shows `2012-05-07T07:00:00Z`. However I do not know what type of date time is this. I need to know because I will be converting that to UNIX timestamp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That timestamp is in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations). The `T` in the middle separates the date part (on the left, in yyyy-mm-dd format) from the time (on the right, in hh:mm:ss). The `Z` indicates that the timestamp is in UTC.

Comment: wow thanks dude, any idea how to convert to unix timestamp in php? strtotime?

Comment: According to the PHP documentation, it looks like strtotime will do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Example: 1336346440 (2012-05-06 23:20:40Z)